# Deploy dacpac as nuget

Tags: nuget, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I'm trying figuring out how to handle dacpac files as nuget for our solution.

We have a huge database created and handled by a SSDT project that produces a dacpac.

We would like to create a pipeline in DevOps for creating a nuget package from that with a certain version, publishing it to Artifact. So everyone can download it and recreate the database locally.

is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .nuspec file in the SQL project like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>My.Database.Dacpac</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>You</authors>
    <description>Dacpac of My.Database</description>
  </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="bin\Release\*.dacpac"/>
    </files>
</package>
```

Then in the pipeline create the nuget and push it:

```
  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: "Build"
    inputs:
      solution: '**\*.sln'
      configuration: 'Release'
      clean: true
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: "Create nuget"
    inputs:
      command: 'pack'
      packagesToPack: '.nuspec'
      configuration: 'Release'
      versioningScheme: 'off'
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Push nuget"
    inputs:
      command: 'push'
      packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
      nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
      publishVstsFeed: 'Change this to your feed'
```

And to use it in your project, first install it and then modify to add the GeneratePathProperty:

```
<PackageReference Include="My.Database.Dacpac" Version="1.0.1">
    <GeneratePathProperty>true</GeneratePathProperty>
</PackageReference>
```

Then you have to add this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(PkgMy_Database_Dacpac)\My.Database.dacpac">
        <Link>My.Database.dacpac</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <Pack>true</Pack>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

With all this, you will have the dacpac file in the output directory and also in your solution as a linked file from the nuget.